# Unable to login or change password on WSL (during 'install')

Tags: system-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to use and install WSL in my Windows environment, but I"m getting errors in changing passwords or logging into the WSL environment.

[image: Look at this]

How can I get past this?

Comment: I think you're a little confused.  You've already got Ubuntu installed in WSL, or you wouldn't have the prompt you have.  What makes you think it's not installed?  (When you open it, it will default log you in as the 'user' it created when it was first installed on the system; so this WSL has already been installed, and configured, so you don't have to 'install' anything, and you were in a `root` prompt so you're already logged in)

Answer (score 0):

From what can be seen in the terminal, you are trying to set a password. By default, WSL has created a root user with username "root" and no password.

You are already logged in as root. Now if you want to change the root password, you need to run `passwd` and then provide a password when prompted for *New password*. Then again you have to type that same password when prompted for *Retype new password*.

Instead, if you want to create a new (non-root) user, you need to run `useradd <username>`. Then run `passwd <username>` to set the password for that user. After that, run `login` and provide the credentials of the newly created user.

Comment: I have tried that and have not reached any success whatsoever?